# How to work with resources if "Resources and images" are empty

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, embedded-resource

I opened a old projcet where I put resources using XE2 IDE/Project/"Resources and images..." feature.

I put 4 png images there and corresponding .red and .dres file were created.

Now If i open "Resources and images..." again I see nothing, but the application behaves well and it's able to extract the 4 files.

How to restore "Resources and images..." so that i can see and replace the files?

Thanks

Note: this is what i mean with "I see nothing":
[image: ide SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Is there a file with odares extension in your project folder?

Comment: I have dres, identcache, res, rc, no odares, i also made sure res and dres are not readonly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using that dialog to add resources results in modifications to the .dproj file. That's the master source. Your .dproj file should have items like this:

```
<RcItem Include="Chrysanthemum.jpg">
    <ResourceType>RCDATA</ResourceType>
    <ResourceId>JpgImage_1</ResourceId>
</RcItem>
```

The compiler will use the information from the .dproj file to create and compile a .rc file and name the output .dres. That .dres file is then linked to your application.

If those items are present in the .dproj file, then items will appear in that dialog. If your .dproj file has been lost and re-created then the items will not appear in that dialog. That's the most likely explanation for what you observe. You'll need to add the files again, and make sure that you look after your .dproj file. I trust it is in your revision control system?

The reason why you can still get hold of the images at runtime is that the .dres file is still present and is still linked in when you re-build the application. But the .dres file is not being re-created because the settings have been lost from the .dproj file.

Comment: Yes you are right. I simply deleted my local res, dres, dpr, dproj files and synced again from VCS. And now I see all as expected. thanks